# Числа Фибоначчи. Не проходит 6 тест на acmp

Tags: c++, математика, олимпиада, числа-фибоначчи

Последовательностью Фибоначчи называется последовательность чисел F0 = 0, F1 = 1, … , Fk = Fk-1 + Fk-2 (k > 1).
Требуется найти наибольший общий делитель двух чисел Фибоначчи.

**Входные данные**
Во входном файле INPUT.TXT записаны два целых числа i и j (1 ≤ i, j ≤ 10^6).

**Выходные данные**
В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите остаток от деления НОД чисел Fi и Fj на 10^9.

**Вот мой код:**

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

long double nod(long double a, long double b)
{

    if (a == b) {
        return a;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        long double tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
    return nod(a, b - a);
}

long double fib(int n)
{
    double a = 0.0;
    double b = 1.0;
    double temp = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp = b;
        b += a;
        a = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j; // вводимые числа

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("INPUT.TXT");
    fin >> i >> j;
    fin.close();

    long double Fi = fib(i); // число Фибоначчи от i
    long double Fj = fib(j); // число Фибоначчи от j

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("OUTPUT.TXT");
    fout << fmod(nod(Fi, Fj), 1000000000); //остаток от деления НОД чисел Fi и Fj на 10^9
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Гм, вы всерьез собираетесь считать миллионное число фибоначчи? :)

Comment: Намекаю (уж очень не хочется писать готовое решение за вас...) -

НОД(F_n,F_m) = F_{НОД(n,m)}

Если уж совсем никак - ну, пишите... напишу вам эти 22 строчки полного решения (с красивым форматированием; без него (а также для тех компиляторов, где уже реализована стандартная `gcd`) - и того меньше...) Простите за форматирование a la TeX, но в комментариях иначе не получается...

Comment: Кстати, если это задача с https://acmp.ru/ - не заморачивайтесь с файлами, они позволяют читать из `cin` и писать в `cout`...

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста. у меня не получается

Comment: Ох, нечестно это получается... Вы уж хотя бы не просто выдайте за свой, а разберитесь, как он работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, еще раз - смотрим в [Википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8) и видим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значит, нам нужно найти НОД для чисел `i` и `j` из условия, после чего найти соответствующее число Фибоначчи по модулю 1000000000. Все.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Поиск НОД
int gcd(int m, int n)
{
    while(m && n) if (m < n) n %= m; else m %= n;
    return m + n;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, f0 = 0, f1 = 1;
    cin >> i >> j;                 // Считали i, j
    for(i = gcd(i,j); i > 0; --i)  // Ищем нужное число...
    {
        int f = (f0+f1)%1000000000;// ... по модулю 1000000000!!
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = f;
    }
    cout << f0 << endl;       // Собственно, всё.
}
```